# Conditional Regex does not behave as expected in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out the exact behavior of the conditional logic in Regex with Python. For this, I have made up a test that works as I would have expected in Regex101 using the Python flavor, but not in Python. The pattern is:

`(hello)?(?(1) world| bye)`

And test cases:

```
hello world
hello bye
something bye
```

In Regex101 this matches `hello world` in full and the  `bye` in `something bye`.

In Python, this only matches `hello world` - I would have expected it to match the  `bye` in `something bye` too?

Would be amazing if someone could help me understand where I'm misunderstanding this implementation? In Python, my code is:

```
tests = ['hello world', 'something bye', 'something world']

for t in tests:
    print(re.match("(hello)?(?(1) world| bye)", t))
```

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Ci6RoE, use `re.search`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew brilliant, thanks!